# Can the HWND from CreateWindow/CreateDialog be GetMessage'd from another thread?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

Using the Win32 APIs, is it possible to create a Window or Dialog in one thread then collect events for it from another thread?

Are HWNDs tied to threads?

Trying the contrived example below I never see GetMessage() fire.

```
HWND g_hWnd;

DWORD WINAPI myThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    while(GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
       ...
    }

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) 
{
    hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG), 0, myDlgProc);
    CreateThread(NULL, 0 myThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    ...
}
```

But here, I do.

```
HWND g_hWnd;
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;

DWORD WINAPI myThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG), 0, myDlgProc);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
       ...
    }

}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) 
{
    g_hInstance = hInstance;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0 myThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    ...
}
```

Can somebody explain what I'm seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

GetMessage returns messages on the current thread's input queue.  The HWND parameter is a filter, so that GetMessage only returns messages in the current thread's input queue intended for that window.

Windows have thread affinity - messages intended for a window get handled on the thread that created and therefore owns the window.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936(VS.85).aspx):

> The GetMessage function retrieves a
>   message from the calling thread's
>   message queue

So no, what you describe is not directly possible.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example the Dialog and [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936(VS.85).aspx) are in separate threads. And the documentation says:

> The GetMessage function retrieves a message from the calling thread's message queue.

The second example works since the calling thread (for `GetMessage`) also owns the `Dialog`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AttachThreadInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Not possible on Windows CE/Mobile.

Comment: Recommending use of a dangerous API, without even mentioning the consequences, is grossly negligent. **-1**.

Comment: This links together the GetMessage calls for all those threads. They all have to be calling it at the same time, before a message will go to any of them.

Answer (score 0):

In your example programm finish after create window.

But anyway in win32 all threads have own message queue.

And all message queues get messages for windows created in this thread.

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928(VS.85).aspx (Using Messages and Message Queues)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936(VS.85).aspx (GetMessage Function)

Answer (score -1):

You can of course change the window procedure that handles messages for any window.  Check the SetWindowLong function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591(VS.85).aspx - there are some rules as to what address space the new proc is.  I suggest using a dll.  Another way is to sub class the window message queue.