# WINAPI's message loops drives me crazy

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, java-native-interface

I've been trying to implement simple low level keyhook using JNI and all went well til I figured I can't call the methods while the DLL is on infinite loop(message loop). so I decided to create new thread but somehow, after I made it so the message loop runs on its own loop the lowlevel keyhook stops responding meaning that it doesn't call the keyproc anymore, and I got no idea why is this? is there any other work around for this? I am required to be able to call the DLL's methods while the keyboard hook is still functioning.

My current code is as simple as

register keyboard hook:

```
keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
```

start thread

```
HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, &threadId);
```

my keyboard proc and threadproc are the following:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpVoid) {
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT keyEvent = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
    jint vkCode = keyEvent.vkCode;
    jint flags = keyEvent.flags;
    jint action = wParam;
    (*globalEnv).CallVoidMethod(globalObj, keyboardMethodId, vkCode, flags, action);
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

where do I go wrong?
I am sure it not the java as even if I add simple logging for the keyproc its never called. But if I stop using thread and run the message loop on main thread it works fine but DLL wont respond for method calls after it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617248/can-the-hwnd-from-createwindow-createdialog-be-getmessaged-from-another-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pump the message loop on the same thread that called SetWindowsHookEx().  So just move the call to your ThreadProc().  And of course, beware that your CallVoidMethod() callback runs on that same thread as well so be careful what you do in that function.  Any shared state you access needs to be protected with a lock.

Comment: You made some valid point there. I'll move the call there and try it out! Is the lock only to make sure two threads don't have concurrent access to mess up some data?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to install desktop-wide hook, which spans across all processes of the desktop. That is, your DLL is mapped into several processes with process-specific sets of global variables. You don't have valid `globalEnv` in other processes and you are likely to get access violations or similar errors (global vars can be created with shared data segment, see [this article for details](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed)).

To install thread specific hook you will need a different type of hook (`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is global only!) and non-zero last argument in `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, I need dektop-wide hook to attach shortcut keys etc. and it works well, til I attempt to run the message loop on external thread, is it even possible? I only need the dll to be able to respond my method calls after I've attached the hook.

Comment: what is your `globalEnv` then?

Comment: Too bad one can't accept to answer, you were such a great help! :) Thanks dude, got it working! :P

Comment: Actually Hans is correct above - this hook is not injected into other processes and works on the calling thread instead, so having message pump running on the `SetWindowsHookEx` call thread is the key to resolve this sort of the problem.