# Win32 - GetMessage from another thread

Tags: winapi, getmessage

According to this thread: [Can the HWND from CreateWindow/CreateDialog be GetMessage'd from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617248/can-the-hwnd-from-createwindow-createdialog-be-getmessaged-from-another-thread), it seems that I can't use GetMessage in another thread using the main thread's HWND.

I'm simply trying to grab the value inside an edittext using GetMessage which is called from a new thread. What are some ways I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value from an edit control you don't actually use `GetMessage` at all. `GetMessage` is for **receiving** messages, but to get the text from a window you have to **send** it a message - i.e. you use `SendMessage`.

The message to send is `WM_GETTEXT` (preceeded by `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`). Or even easier, use one of the wrapper functions the OS provides for you - in this instance `GetWindowText` or `GetDlgItemText`. They work across thread boundaries just fine (and in fact even across process boundaries).

Comment: "Or even easier, use one of the wrapper functions the OS provides for you - in this instance GetWindowText or GetDlgItemText" - highly controversial advice: for example, after version 6  Spy++ its authors even replaced GetWindowText  on SendMessage (WM_GETTEXT)...

Comment: Citation? GetWindowText just sends WM_GETTEXT for threads in the same process, there's no effective difference. Cross-process it's even better as it won't hang if the target process is non-responsive whereas sending the message yourself would.

Comment: Please - citation: "Copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied. However, GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application". (GetWindowText, MSDN)